# React Native, expo notififaction. Not getting the notitifaction, what can be the problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to use react native, expo notifications. I want to get notifaction pushed localy to me from the app if it is closed or open.

The starting time is when you are awake,
The endtime is when you go to sleep.
notificationCount is how many counts you want to get.

Well it works in away that is not saying there is a problem, but I do not get any notification from this peace of code that I will show you

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';

const NotificationScheduler = () => {
  const startTime = new Date();
  // Start time: 02:00 adjust, (hour, min, 0, 0)
  startTime.setHours(2, 0, 0, 0); 
  const endTime = new Date();
  // End time: 03:30 adjust, (hour, min, 0, 0)
  endTime.setHours(3, 30, 0, 0); 
  // Number of notifications, How many times you want to get notification.. 
  // ATTH; Higher number is just to get them more frequently while testing.
  const notificationCount = 240; 
  // This is just to get the message displayed on the screen if any, if it does, and no notification
  // is displayed, then something is working but not as it should.
  const [notificationMessage, setNotificationMessage] = useState('No notifications yet.');
  // Getting the difference on time, to calculate the frequent interval on the time. 
  const timeDifference = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
  // Making the interval.
  const interval = Math.max(1, Math.round(timeDifference / notificationCount));

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure I have permission to send notifiactions
    const requestPermissions = async () => {
      const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        // if not please go to settings and allow them
        alert('Please go to settings and allow notifications!');
        return;
      }
    };

    requestPermissions();

    // The scheduler for notification.
[2:21 AM]
const scheduleNotifications = async () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  console.log('------ Starts  ------')
  for (let i = 1; i < notificationCount; i++) {
    // making the trigger for sending notifications on spesific time and sqedule them.
    const trigger = new Date(startTime.getTime() + i * interval);
    console.log('trigger : ' + trigger);
    // Setting up the notififactions
    await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
      content: {
        title: "Time to check!",
        body:`This is notification number ${i + 1}.`,
        data: { data: 'data goes here'},
      },
      trigger: {
        ...trigger,
        repeats: true,
      },
    });
  }
};

const notificationListener = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
  setNotificationMessage(notification.request.content.body);
});

const foregroundNotificationListener = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
  setNotificationMessage(response.notification.request.content.body);
});

scheduleNotifications();

return () => {
  Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener);
  Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(foregroundNotificationListener);
};
}, []);

return (
<View>
  <Text>Notifications scheduled!</Text>
  <Text>Latest Notification: {notificationMessage}</Text>
</View>
);
};

export default NotificationScheduler;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, thank god. The solution is simple.
`

```
for (let i = 1; i <= notificationCount; i++) {
        // making the trigger for sending notifications on spesific time and sqedule them.
        const triggerHour = new Date(startTime.getTime() + i * interval).getHours();
        const triggerMin = new Date(startTime.getTime() + i * interval).getMinutes();
     
        console.log('triggerhour : ' + triggerHour + '  Triggermin : ' +triggerMin);
        // Setting up the notififactions
        const sec = i * 15;
        await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
          content: {
            title: "Time to check!",
            body:'This is notification hour : ' + triggerHour + '. og ' + triggerMin + ' min.',
            data: { data: 'data goes here'},
          },
          trigger: {
            hour: triggerHour,
            minute: triggerMin,
            repeats: true,
          },
        });
      }
```

`

Since I was only looking for repeats at a specific time on each day this should do. But I am not sure if I need to add more features to this. Do I need to garbage collect the notifications later, or is it enough to set them to false later?